# Making own iptables rules in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, iptables

I am using ubuntu 14.04, and I want to build my own firewall.
How can I make an iptables rule for a specific user - *to not allow him to make something...* ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're after - but just in case - module owner (ipt_owner) may be helpful for you.

Comment: See this link: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/block-outgoing-network-access-for-a-single-user-from-my-server-using-iptables.html#more-900

Comment: You might just want to get a firewall, not build one.

Comment: you can use ufw https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04